# data display issue while map inside find

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using to find method inside mapping data in MUITable, while using find method when ever I pass static data ( "C873" ) works fine but when I pass dynamic data ( item.referal_id ) project will not work throw blank page ,

```js
let data = [
    {agent_id: "325D" , email: "Ramm@c.m", name: "Ramm" ,referal_id:  "C873" ,state:  "U.P"},
    {agent_id: "C873" , email: "Aamm@com", name: "Aman" ,referal_id:  "7CC8" ,state:  "M.P"}
  ];

// data array almost look same as above

<div className="mi-table">
            <MUIDataTable
              title={"Agent List"}
              data={data.data.map((item, i) => (
                [item.name,item.referal_id ? data.data.find(o => o.agent_id == "C873").name : '', item.referal_id, item.state]
              ))}
            columns={columns}
            options={options}
            />
</div>
```

[It works fine Image -](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Atiqf.png)

```js
let data = [
    {agent_id: "325D" , email: "Ramm@c.m", name: "Ramm" ,referal_id:  "C873" ,state:  "U.P"},
    {agent_id: "C873" , email: "Aamm@com", name: "Aman" ,referal_id:  "7CC8" ,state:  "M.P"}
  ];

// data array almost look same as above

<div className="mi-table">
            <MUIDataTable
              title={"Agent List"}
              data={data.data.map((item, i) => (
                [item.name,item.referal_id ? data.data.find(o => o.agent_id == item.referal_id).name : '', item.referal_id, item.state]
              ))}
            columns={columns}
            options={options}
            />
</div>
```

[it is not Image -](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpaSh.png)

I don't understand why I am getting this issue, how can I resolve it?

I have tried to pass static data it's works but  when I pass dynamic data project will not work throw blank page

Comment: Please include all code as text, not images.

Comment: What debugging have you done? Are there errors in the console? It's probably breaking because your `find` is returning `undefined` and you're still trying to get a name from it.

Comment: @Andy yes , you are right I am getting ( Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') )

so how can I resolve it

Comment: The difference is that in your second snippet, you may not find any result in your `data.data.find(o => o.agent_id == item.referal_id)` (Since there is no match for "7CC8") Leaving you with `undefined`, which has no `.name` property.

Comment: yeah @DBS I understand your point, but still I am not understand how can I resolve

Comment: Well, if you are ok passing `undefined` into the component, you could just do `)?.name` which will use the `.name` property if it exists, or fall back to `undefined`. (Here's the MDN page covering this, it's called [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining))